# A question about cluster point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I have just completed learning basic topology. I need a help regarding solutuion verfication regarding the following problem.

**Statement:** Let $X$ be a compact $T_1$ topological space and let $M:=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an infinite subset of $X$. Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous function, where $Y$ is a metric space. Let $x_0$ be an accumulation point of $M$. Then $f(x_0)$ is a subsequential limit of $(f(x_n)).$

**Proof** Consider a neighborhood system $\{U_k: k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ at $f(x_0)$, where $U_k=B_{\frac{1}{k}}(f(x_0))$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(U_k)$ is open for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Note that for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$f^{-1}(U_k) \cap M \neq \emptyset.$$
Let $A_m :=\{x_0, x_1,x_2, \dots, x_m\}$. Choose $x_{n_1}\in f^{-1}(U_1)\cap M$ such that $x_{n_1}\neq x_0$. Since $X$ is $T_1$, $A_{n_1}$ is closed and, therefore, $f^{-1}(U_2)\setminus A_{n_1}$ is still open in $X$. Also,
$$(f^{-1}(U_2)\setminus A_{n_1})\cap M \neq \emptyset.$$
Choose $x_{n_2}\in M$ such that $x_{n_2}\in f^{-1}(U_2)\setminus A_{n_1}.$ Continuing thus, we can construct an infinite set $\{x_{n_k}:k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that $n_j> n_p$ for $j>p$ and
$$x_{n_k}\in f^{-1}(U_k)~\mathrm{for~each}~k.$$
Choose any $\varepsilon >0$ and choose a natural number $p$ such that $\frac{1}{p}< \varepsilon$. Then for all $k\geq p$,
$f(x_{n_k})\in U_p.$ Therefore,
$$d(f(x_{n_k}),f(x_0))< \frac{1}{p} < \varepsilon.$$
Therefore, $(f(x_{n_k})) \to f(x_0)$. Therefore, $f(x_0)$ is a subsequential limit of $(f(x_n))$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks quite correct. You could also use the basic fact that $x_0$ is an $\omega$-accumulation point of $M$, so that every neighbourhood of $x_)$ contains infinitely many points of $M$. This follows from $X$ being $T_1$ and $x_0$ being a limit point. Then indeed pick the $x_{n_k}$ recursively so that $x_{n_k} \in f^{-1}[B(f(x_0), \frac{1}{k})]$ with increasing indexes $n_1, n_2 ,\ldots$, using the fact that we have infinitely many choices. Then you separate the two things you use more cleanly ($T_1$ to get infinitely many choices in the domain, and the local countable base at $f(x_0)$ to get a convergent sequence there).

It's a matter of style really.

BTW if you assume $X$ is compact then $M$ has an $\omega$-accumulation point regardless of $X$ being $T_1$ or not. You otherwise don't use the compactness, which now is a superfluous condition,as $x_0$ is given to exist anyway.

Comment: Thankyou @HennoBrandsma for your answer.

Comment: I agree with your edit